# Forms (Select and radio buttons) have different colors in FF and Chrome

Tags: css

I am working on a web site and both, the select box and the part with radio buttons, have different colors in FF and Chrome. The problem is located here:
https://authentic-translation.de/unternehmen/kontakt-und-anfrage/

The select is the first element in the second row ("Anrede") and the text with radio buttons is the element in the 9th row ("Das genannte Datum ist flexibel    Ja
Nein")

If I choose a color (CSS) that is OK in FF, it is not OK in Chrome and vice versa. Does anybody know  an easy hack how to resolve this? Can I override it with jQuery?

Thanks!
Raphael

Comment: Please make a minimal reproducible example and put it in your question rather than point to an external site. It will make it much easier to help you. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I dont know how to create an example. It is in that code of the website that causes somehow the problem, and I have no glue what creates exactly  the change in the color. Therefore I do not know how to reproduce the problem. I never had such a thing with select boxes. 

I could install a library for targeting the selects, but how can I fix the problem with the radio button?